# C# Using a Class as object in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, class, object, printing, dictionary

I'm a newbie on C# and I have some issues with a code I'm trying to write.

I have to make a simple program that stores some info on students and later, let me get the info to print.

My idea was this: I created a class, named "Aluno" and implemented a series of methods to set and get the info I needed, and then I passed this class as parameter to a Dictionary Something like this:

```
 class Aluno
    {
        private int matricula;
        private string nomeCompleto;

        public int getMatricula() { return matricula; }
        public string getNomeCompleto() { return nomeCompleto;

        public void setMatricula(int m)
        {
            matricula = m;
        }
        public void setNomeCompleto(string nome)
        {
            nomeCompleto = nome;
        }
```

Then i used it in a dictionaty

```
        Dictionary<int,object> principal =  new Dictionary<int,object>();
        Aluno a = new Aluno();

        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe a matricula:");
        a.setMatricula(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o nome completo do aluno:");
        a.setNomeCompleto(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

        principal.Add(a.getMatricula(), a);
```

After this, I implemented a class to print the info stored on dictionary:

```
class ImprimeListagem
    {
        public static void listagemSimples(Dictionary<int,object> origem)
        {
            int contador = 0;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> chave in origem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(chave.Key+"|"+chave.Value);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
```

when I use Visual studio to "look" inside chave.value, all the info stored is there, but I cant access it. Can someone help me?
I'll print the entire code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int QTDE_ALUNO_PRINCIPAL = 1;
        const int QTDE_ALUNO_RESERVA = 1;            
        int contadorAlunosPrincial = 0;
        int contadorAlunoReserva = 0;


        Dictionary<int,object> principal =  new Dictionary<int,object>();
        Queue<object> espera = new Queue<object>();

        Aluno a = new Aluno();

        int opcao = 0;



        do
        {
            ImprimeMenu.imprimirMenuPrincipal();
            opcao = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (opcao)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (contadorAlunosPrincial < QTDE_ALUNO_PRINCIPAL)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe a matricula:");
                        a.setMatricula(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o nome completo do aluno:");
                        a.setNomeCompleto(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o nome da mãe:");
                        a.setNomeDaMae(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o nome do pai:");
                        a.setNomeDoPai(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o país");
                        a.setEnderecoPais(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o estado:");
                        a.setEnderecoEstado(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe a rua e o numero");
                        a.setEnderecoRuaNumero(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o cep");
                        a.setEnderecoCep(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                        Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o telefone para contato:");
                        a.setTelefoneContato(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

                        principal.Add(a.getMatricula(), a);

                        contadorAlunosPrincial++;

                    }
                    else
                        if (contadorAlunoReserva < QTDE_ALUNO_RESERVA)
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe a matricula:");
                            a.setMatricula(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o nome completo do aluno:");
                            a.setNomeCompleto(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o nome da mãe:");
                            a.setNomeDaMae(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o nome do pai:");
                            a.setNomeDoPai(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o país");
                            a.setEnderecoPais(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o estado:");
                            a.setEnderecoEstado(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe a cidade:");
                            a.setEnderecoCidade(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o bairro:");
                            a.setEnderecoBairro(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe a rua e o numero");
                            a.setEnderecoRuaNumero(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o cep");
                            a.setEnderecoCep(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                            Console.WriteLine("Por favor informe o telefone para contato:");
                            a.setTelefoneContato(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

                            espera.Enqueue(a);

                            contadorAlunoReserva++;
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("Não há mais vagas para cadastro de Alunos!\nTente novamente mais tarde.");

                    break;

                case 2:
                    ImprimeMenu.imprimirMenuSecundário();
                    opcao = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    switch (opcao)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            ImprimeListagem.listagemSimples(principal);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

            }
        } while (opcao != 7);

    }

    class ImprimeMenu
    {
        public static void imprimirMenuPrincipal()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Programa de cadastro de alunos! Escolha a opção desejada.\n\n" +
                "1 – Cadastrar aluno\n" +
                "2 – Imprimir lista de alunos\n" +
                "3 – Imprimir lista de espera\n" +
                "4 – Pesquisar aluno\n" +
                "5 – Desistência\n" +
                "6 – Sorteio\n" +
                "7 – Sair");
        }
        public static void imprimirMenuSecundário()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("2 – Imprimir lista de alunos\n\n" +
                "\t1 – Listagem simples\n" +
                "\t2 – Listagem completa");
        }
    }

    class Aluno
    {
        public Aluno()
        {
            matricula = 0;
            nomeCompleto = null;
            nomeDaMae = null;
            nomeDoPai = null;
            enderecoPais = null;
            enderecoEstado = null;
            enderecoCidade = null;
            enderecoBairro = null;
            enderecoRuaNumero = null;
            enderecoCep = null;
            telefoneContato = null; 
        }            

        private int matricula;
        private string nomeCompleto;
        private string nomeDaMae;
        private string nomeDoPai;
        private string enderecoPais;
        private string enderecoEstado;
        private string enderecoCidade;
        private string enderecoBairro;
        private string enderecoRuaNumero;
        private string enderecoCep;
        private string telefoneContato;

        public void setMatricula(int m)
        {
            matricula = m;
        }

        public void setNomeCompleto(string nome)
        {
            nomeCompleto = nome;
        }

        public void setNomeDaMae(string nomeMae)
        {
            nomeDaMae = nomeMae;
        }

        public void setNomeDoPai(string nomePai)
        {
            nomeDoPai = nomePai;
        }

        public void setEnderecoPais(string pais)
        {
            enderecoPais =  pais;
        }

        public void setEnderecoEstado(string estado)
        {
            enderecoEstado = estado;
        }

        public void setEnderecoCidade(string cidade)
        {
            enderecoCidade = cidade;
        }

        public void setEnderecoBairro(string bairro)
        {
            enderecoBairro = bairro;
        }

        public void setEnderecoRuaNumero(string ruaNumero)
        {
            enderecoRuaNumero = ruaNumero;
        }

        public void setEnderecoCep(string cep)
        {
            enderecoCep = cep;
        }

        public void setTelefoneContato(string telefone)
        {
            telefoneContato = telefone;
        }

        public int getMatricula() { return matricula; }
        public string getNomeCompleto() { return nomeCompleto; }
        public string getNomeDaMae() { return nomeDaMae; }
        public string getEnderecoPais() { return enderecoPais; }
        public string getEnderecoEstado() { return enderecoEstado; }
        public string getEnderecoCidade() { return enderecoCidade; }
        public string getEnderecoBairro() { return enderecoBairro; }
        public string getEnderecoRuaNumero() { return enderecoRuaNumero; }
        public string getEnderecoCep() { return enderecoCep; }
        public string getTelefoneContato() { return telefoneContato; }           

    }

    class ImprimeListagem
    {
        public static void listagemSimples(Dictionary<int,object> origem)
        {

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> chave in origem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(chave.Key+"|"+chave.Value);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }            
    }
```

Thanks in advance and sorry about my poor english, it's not my native language. :D

Comment: Off-topic, but are you aware that you could use `Matriculo` and `NomeCompleto` [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), rather than separate getter and setter methods. C# ain't Java.

Comment: I was not, thnks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
Dictionary<int,Aluno> principal =  new Dictionary<int,Aluno>();
```

In general it is extremely rare when one need to use `object` and parameter of generic type. In most cases you should use concrete type (or interface).

If you really find yourself with `object value;` instead of concrete type - you can cast it to type you expect "value" to be: `MyType = (MyType)value;`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that is what I wanted, sorry about the newbie question. :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly cast the `Object` that you  get from Dictionary to your class `Aluno` like this `((Aluno)chave.Value)`